# How does FastAPI access a PostgreSQL custom function which accepts a user input and returns a table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I am getting an error
`422 Unprocessable Entity' '{"detail": [{"loc": ["body"], "msg": "field required", "type": "value_error.missing"}]}`

```
from typing import Optional, List, Any, Generator
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException, status
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Numeric, Enum
from sqlalchemy.sql import text, select, func, column
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, as_declarative, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from pydantic import BaseModel, condecimal

from enums import Colour
from config import settings


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = settings.DATABASE_URL
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                            autoflush=False,
                            bind=engine)

def get_db() -> Generator:
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@as_declarative()
class Base:
    id: Any
    __name__: str

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__.lower()

class Pct(Base):
    pid = Column(Integer, primary_key= True, nullable= False)
    nm = Column(String, nullable= False)
    p = Column(Numeric(70,67), nullable= False)
    yr = Column(Integer, nullable= False)
    color = Column(Enum(Colour), default=Colour.unknown)
    kind = Column(String, nullable= False)

class PctBase(BaseModel):
    pid: int
    nm: str
    p: condecimal(max_digits=70, decimal_places=67)
    yr: int
    color: Optional[Colour]
    kind: str

def retrieve_pct(id: int, pct: PctBase, db: Session):
    pct_object = Pct(**pct.dict())
    pct_stmt = text('SELECT * FROM ptigree(:pid)', {'pid': id})
    db.execute(pct_stmt)
    db.commit()
    return pct_object

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/get/{id}", response_model= List[PctBase])
def read_pct(id: int, pct: PctBase, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    pct = retrieve_pct(pct= pct, db= db, id= id)
    return pct
```

I am wanting to send the SQL function `ptigree` an `id` chosen by my users. After `ptigree` generates the result set (multi-row table with columns: `pid`, `nm`, `p`, `yr`, `color`, `kind`), I want the API endpoint to show those results to my user.

I was able to get it working per advice given below. The changes involved 1) making `pct_recieve` fetch an actual result with SqlAlchemy:

```
def retrieve_pct(id: int, db: Session):
    pct_func = func.ptigree(id).table_valued(
        column("pid", Integer),
        column("horse_nm", String),
        column("p", Numeric(70,67)),
        column("crop", Integer),
        column("color", Enum(Colour)),
        column("sex", String))
    pct_stmt = select(pct_func)
    pct_result = db.execute(pct_stmt)
    db.commit
    return pct_result
```

and processing the result for Pydantic to read the table row by row in `read_pct`:

```
@router.get("/get/{id}", response_model= List[PctBase])
def read_pct(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    pct_result = retrieve_pct(id= id, db= db)
    pct_objects = [PctBase(**row._asdict()) for row in pct_result]
    return pct_objects
```

In PgAdmin, I can verify that the SQL function works by using a statement:

```
SELECT * FROM ptigree(some_integer);
```

to which it returns the expected five column table with a varying number of rows.

I have spent awhile looking through documentation and other questions but haven't had success understanding how to solve this:

How does FastAPI access a PostgreSQL custom function which accepts a user input and returns a table?

Comment: I don't really understand, what you are trying to do in `retrieve_pct`, but it seems that you are executing a `SELECT` query and not doing anything with the output. Wouldn't you want to capture what it returns in some variable? I mean you are calling the session's `execute` method without assigning the results to anything. Could you elaborate on what is going on there?

Comment: I want ```retrieve_pct``` to take a user provided `id` and send it to my PostgreSQL function called `ptigree`. PostgreSQL takes that `id` as the focus of a recursive cte and returns a table with 5 columns (pid, nm, p, yr, color, kind). I want ```retrieve_pct``` to return that output to the API endpoint for my user. I can get PgAdmin to access my `ptigree` function and return the desired five-column table using ```SELECT * FROM ptigree(some_integer);``` I can't seem to get that table back out to the API endpoint.

Comment: But you're **not capturing anything** returned from that DB query. The [`Session.execute`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.execute) method returns a result object with whatever that query produced. These are all [SQLAlchemy basics](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#tutorial-fetching-rows) that are well documented. You can read up on how to return data fetched from the DB all over the place.

Comment: Thank you Daniil, I've tried to capture the result per SqlAlchemy with `return pct_result` in the amended retrieve_pct, but the same error persists. I still have an unprocessable entity. Am I misunderstanding what you are driving at?